# How to make image background white instead of black?

Tags: image, colors, background, kivy

I am a beginner. I have this kv code:

<Pat_layout>:

```
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            id: name_label
            text:  "Exercises Appear Here"
            font_size: 32

        Image:
            id: image_window
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            source: 'images/dim_6543.jpg'

        Button:
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0, .3, .4, .95
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            font_size: 32
            text: "Press For Next Exercise"
            on_press: root.press()
```

And I get this:
[output image with label, image, button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2O0Z.png)

The chord diagram should have a white background. I have searched and tried things for hours, days. How can I get the middle section, the image, to show a white background around the chord diagram? The chord diagram does not have any surrounding background; it's been cropped to just the diagram.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated....

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to draw a white rectangle filling the Image. The code for this is something like:

```
Image:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Answer (score 0):

Yay, thanks inclement! I copied your code in and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Jim